# How to manually specify color fill for two different grouping variables using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ggplot2 to create a grouped bar plot, but I would like to be able to control the colors for the two different grouping variables separately. E.g., in the mgp data, I can use scale_fill_manual() to specify the colors for the number of cylinders, but I would like to also control the colors for car class, so that e.g. all midsize car data are blue, but are different shades of blue depending on the number of cylinders. I have searched and searched, but have not been able to find a solution for this.

```
ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = class, fill = factor(cyl)),
           position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single')) +
           scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))
```

Comment: A simple approach would be to map the car class on `fill` and the number of cylinders on `alpha`.

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I wanted. Do you want to post it as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Thx ethanweed. I just added my comment as an answer. Best S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to achieve your desired result would be to map the car class on `fill` and the number of cylinders on `alpha`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = class, fill = class, alpha = factor(cyl)),
           position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single')) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(.25, .5, .75, 1))
```

[image]